# Title на шапке страницы

Tags: html, css

помогите пожалуйста сделать текст относительно центра картинки!

[image: скриншот проблемы]

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.header {
    background-color: rgb(101, 192, 253);
    width: 100%;
}
.headerlogoandtitle {
    display: inline-block;
}
.headertext {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css" />
    <!-- Page title -->
    <title>МАОУ Гимназия №1 - официальный сайт</title>
    <script></script>
  </head>
    <body>
      <div class="header">
        <div class="headercont">
          <div class="headerlogoandtitle">
            <img class="logo" src="../assets/logotip.jpg" alt="Логотип сайта"> 
            <div class="headertext">Гимназия №1</div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте flexbox для такого простого выравнивания элементов в одном направлении. Там нет ничего сложного. Еще необязательно делать так много оберток в хедере.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.header {
    background-color: rgb(101, 192, 253);
    width: 100%;
    
    /* Выравнивание через flexbox */
    display: flex; /* Включение флексбокса (по умолчанию выравнивает по левому краю и в строку */
    align-items: center; /* Выравнивание по вертикали по центральной оси элементов */
}


.headertext {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

.logo {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img class="logo" src="../assets/logotip.jpg" alt="Логотип сайта"> 
  <h1>Гимназия №1</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* заключи картинку и текст в один блок и после можешь выровнять при помощи flex */
.option1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
/* Можешь выровнять через абсолютное позиционирование */
.option2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
/* Или можно вырованять по высоте через line-height*/
.option3 {
    line-height: --px; /* равно высоте блока родителя*/
}
```